# print values using for loop within foreach loop

Tags: php

I am facing trouble in printing values using for loop within foreach loop.
I am populating dropdown list using foreach loop by defining an array and then marking the values as selected which matches with values retrieved from database but the problem is values are repeating in last dropdown. Here is my code:
First I am converting string values retrieved from database into an array. and the code and output is as follows:

```
foreach($officeDetails as $value){ 
   $str = $value['days'];  
   $arr = explode(", ", $str); 
}
print_r($arr);
```

Output is:

```
 Array ( 
        [0] => Monday 
        [1] => Tuesday 
      ) 
Array ( 
        [0] => Wednesday 
        [1] => Thursday 
        [2] => Friday 
      )
```

Now I am trying to populate a dropdown list using foreach loop with an array called $daysArr(see below in code) and marking the values as selected which are retrieved from database as shown above in an array called $arr. 
Code:

```
 foreach($officeDetails as $value){ 
   $str = $value['days'];  
   $arr = explode(", ", $str); 

<select id="dw" name="days[0][]" class="full-width select2-offscreen" data-init-plugin="select2" multiple="" tabindex="-1">
    <?php $daysArr = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");

    foreach ($daysArr as $days) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
            if ($days == $arr[$i]) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $days; ?>" selected><?php echo $days; ?></option>

            <?php } else { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $days; ?>"><?php echo $days; ?></option>

            <?php } /* end else condition */
        }/* end for condition */
    } /*end foreach loop */
    }
    ?>

</select>
```

So the result is; two select boxes are printed, showing right selected values but the second select box is printing each value of "$days" three times like Monday is showing three times in the dropdown list.

I know its something minor that I am missing, please help me I am badly stuck in a loop and can't get out of it. Your suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards.

Comment: your problem is the foreach and for loop ? overkill. remove for loop and make a key $i => $days. While writing this i see answer is posted =)

Comment: Thanks. I am doing this but its printing just one select box I want two as $arr has two arrays.

Comment: Hii aisha.. Have you solved this issue? coz even i have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try like the following

```
foreach($officeDetails as $j => $value){ 
$str = $value['days'];  
$arr = explode(", ", $str);
<select id="dw" name="days[0][]" class="full-width select2-offscreen" data-init-plugin="select2" multiple="" tabindex="-1">
 <?php   $daysArr = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");

        foreach($daysArr as $i => $days){


             if ($days == $arr[$i]) {
    ?>
<option value="<?php echo $days; ?>" selected><?php echo $days; ?></option>

<?php } else{ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $days; ?>" ><?php echo $days; ?></option>

<?php       } /* end else condition */
    } /*end foreach loop */
?>

</select>
<?php } /*end foreach loop*/ ?>
```

Comment: $arr is in loop , it will override previous values

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. its working fine, but its printing only one array Monday and Tuesday not the second one.

Comment: @syedmohamed its not working correctly because $officeDetails foreach is the parent loop and this select box and other code is within $officeDetails foreach loop.

Comment: @Aisha can you try now

Comment: @syedmohamed thanks a lot for your suggestions but " $str = $officeDetails[$i]['days'];" this is not going to work because "foreach($officeDetails as $value){ " contains select box and "foreach($daysArr as $days){", so I think you first answer was very close it needs some little changes. If you can help I will highly appreciate it. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Aisha do you need multiple select boxes based on the count of array from $officeDetails ?

from your above code you need 2 select boxex right?

Comment: @syedmohamed exactly, you are right. select boxes based on the count of array from $officeDetails and values selected based on $arr per select box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106027/discussion-between-syed-mohamed-and-aisha).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your count, as it seems that is equivalent of 3 from the array posted in the first bit:

```
foreach($daysArr as $days){
if($days == $arr[$i]){
        ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $days; ?>" selected><?php echo $days; ?></option>

    <?php } else{ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $days; ?>" ><?php echo $days; ?></option>

    <?php       } /* end else condition */

        } /*end foreach loop */
    ?>
```