# compare values retrieved from database with existing values of an array

Tags: php

I am posting this question in continuation of my own question at this link:
[print values using for loop within foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940459/print-values-using-for-loop-within-foreach-loop)

I got a very nice solution from one person and the solution is this:

```
foreach($officeDetails as $key=>$value){ 
      $str = $value['days'];
      $arr = explode(", ", $str);

   /*Output of $arr is :
    Array ( 
    [0] => Monday 
    [1] => Tuesday 
  ) 
 Array ( 
    [0] => Wednesday 
    [1] => Thursday 
    [2] => Friday 
  )
 */

      $daysArr = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
      foreach($daysArr as $i => $days){
            echo $arr[$i]."<br/>";

                if( $daysArr[$i] == $arr[$i] ){
                    echo "Selected ---- ".$days."<br/>";
                }else{
                    echo $days."<br/>";
                    }
              }
        }
```

Now, the problem is when I am using this

```
echo $arr[$i]."<br/>";
```

its printing all the values correctly from $arr means "Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday" but when I am comparing two values using if condition:

```
 if( $daysArr[$i] == $arr[$i] ){
```

it is not checking the second array which is:

```
  Array ( 
    [0] => Wednesday 
    [1] => Thursday 
    [2] => Friday 
  )
```

and showing result

```
Monday
Tuesday
```

It means the problem is occurring at if condition not at foreach loop of $daysArr. Please help me why this is happening at if loop. I am totally lost. Your suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Kind Regards.

Comment: can you show what `$value['days']` is... i assume its a string but it is important how it is structured as you have a space in the `explode` delimiter.

Comment: Yes, sure. $value days is as follows: 
Monday, Tuesday

Comment: The second record consists of Wednesday, Thursday, Friday

Comment: Try `$str = str_replace(' ', '', $value['days']);` and remove the space from the explode delimiter.

Comment: Kindly, can you tell me how its going to solve the problem?

Comment: In testing the code worked as expected. I'm just making sure the string supplied that creates the array using explode is consistent.

Comment: Thank you. but its not working at my side.

Answer (score 0):

I think your arrays have different keys/indexs.

Meaning $daysarr[1] = Tuesday but because of your definition $arr[1] = Thursday which then isn't the same. The keys need to match to make a comparision.

Possible solution:

Make $daysarr a template and $arr just a yes/no.

Means:

When Tuesday and Saturday are selected:

```
$daysarr: 
0->Monday
1->Tuesday
2->Wednesday
3->Thursday
4->Friday
5->Saturday

$arr:
0->0
1->1
2->0
3->0
4->0
5->1
```

0 means not selected
1 means selected

Comment: Can you please tell me how to match the indexes as they are two different arrays. or what would you like to suggest about the solution, is it correct way or wrong?

Comment: $arr are two arrays from two different records coming from $officeDetails each time foreach loop runs, in this way when first time when foreach of $officeDetails will execute $arr of Monday tuesday will execute and after printing these values it will go to $officeDetails foreach loop then Wednesday, Thursday, Friday will be printed then how can be its a conflict of indexes. Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I don't get your concept. Just look at the answer above. Maybe it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for this solution. but $arr consists values retrieved from database, so I can not make it yes/no.

Comment: I assumed it only contains which days are selected. In case you are getting the days out of your database think about changing that to numbers.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for it.